# For every column where rows are not null count the not null rows that are in another column

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
  Phenotype1 Phenotype2    t2d
0       True      False   True
1        NaN       True  False
2      False        NaN    NaN
3      False      False   True
```

For `Phenotype1` I want to count the `True` 'False`values in`t2d`only for those rows where`Phenotype1`is not null. I want to do the same for`Phenotype2`. It is obvious how to do this in a loop but I dont want to loop as really there are thousands on phenotypes.

The results should be this:

```
    phenotype  t2d_true  t2d_false
0  Phenotype1         2          0
1  Phenotype2         2          1
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick read into pandas documentation shows that you can use pandas `crosstab` functionality to achieve the same. Here's how you can achieve it :

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Phenotype1': [True, None, False, False],
    'Phenotype2': [False, True, None, False],
    't2d': [True, False, None, True]
})

# Use crosstab to calculate counts
result = pd.crosstab(df.melt(id_vars='t2d', value_vars=['Phenotype1', 'Phenotype2']).dropna(subset=['value'])['variable'], 
                     df.melt(id_vars='t2d', value_vars=['Phenotype1', 'Phenotype2']).dropna(subset=['value'])['t2d'])

# Reset index and column names for desired output
result = result.reset_index().rename(columns={True: 't2d_true', False: 't2d_false', 'variable': 'phenotype'})

print(result)
```

which results in:

```
t2d   phenotype  t2d_false  t2d_true
0    Phenotype1          0         2
1    Phenotype2          1         2
```

Additionally, pandas `pivot_table` functionality could also be used which results in the same output :

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Phenotype1': [True, None, False, False],
    'Phenotype2': [False, True, None, False],
    't2d': [True, False, None, True]
})

# Melt dataframe to long format
df_long = df.melt(id_vars='t2d', value_vars=['Phenotype1', 'Phenotype2']).dropna(subset=['value'])

# Use pivot_table to get counts
result = df_long.pivot_table(index='variable', columns='t2d', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)

# Drop multi-level columns and reset index
result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(0)
result = result.reset_index().rename(columns={True: 't2d_true', False: 't2d_false', 'variable': 'phenotype'})

print(result)
```

```
t2d   phenotype  t2d_false  t2d_true
0    Phenotype1          0         2
1    Phenotype2          1         2
```

Reference : [Pandas cross tab documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), [Pandas Pivot table documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

Answer (score 0):

With boolean mask filtering and concat accumulated sums:

```
m_notna, m_true = df['t2d'].notna(), df['t2d'].eq(True)
out = df[df.filter(like='Pheno').columns].notna()
out = (pd.concat([out.loc[m_notna & m_true, :].sum().rename('t2d_true'), 
                  out.loc[m_notna & ~(m_true), :].sum().rename('t2d_false')], axis=1)
       .reset_index(names='phenotype'))
```

---

```
    phenotype  t2d_true  t2d_false
0  Phenotype1         2          0
1  Phenotype2         2          1
```